# Gremlin GroovyTranslator generates wrong result and fails at remote server

Tags: gremlin

I am using Gremlin java and I found GroovyTranslator adds additional `\` before `$` sign,
and this causes query failing to execute on remote server.

```
GraphTraversal traversal = graph.addV().property("amount", "$1");
System.out.println(GroovyTranslator.of("g").translate(traversal.asAdmin().getBytecode()));
```

Translated result:

```
g.addV().property("amount","\$1")
```

1. If this is issue with GroovyTranslator, i can replace `\$` with `$`, but I am not sure if more special characters will have this issue.
2. This fails because of backslash, but what if some property value want to use backslash?
   From what I see, use backslash will always fail.
   I suppose following should work but it doesn't:

   ```
   curl -X POST -d '{"gremlin":"g.V().has(\"key\",\"\\$\")"}' ...
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy the dollar sign has special meaning if you are using Groovy Strings (GStrings). It is used to indicate interpolation should occur as in :

```
gremlin> a=3
==>3
gremlin> "The number is $a"
==>The number is 3
```

If the server you are connecting to uses Groovy as-is to parse the query then the backslash is needed. If the server does not use Groovy as-is then you will need to remove the backslash.

There are a few other things to be aware of with GroovyTranslator. When it generates literal numbers it puts a cast such as `(int) 3` into the query. You may need to also remove these depending on the back end graph database you are connecting to.

Comment: Does it mean if server does not use Groovy, there is no way to use backslash, i tried escape backslash `\\\`, and query fails

Comment: I was able to use a backslash just fine from the Gremlin console in a test query connected to a remote graph.